# Change in Request XML after passing it to Call webservice via SOAP

Tags: java, soap, axis, websphere-8

below request xml can be formed by service client stub code which is working fine in dev box. The application server is websphere-8.5.5.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><soapenv:Body><getPlanLookUpBySSN xmlns="http://example.com"><argLookupBySSNInput xmlns=""><applicationId>IVR</applicationId><client>PC</client><ivrInd>Y</ivrInd><scrollIndicator></scrollIndicator><scrollKey></scrollKey><ssn>12345</ssn><type>Dental</type><userId>IVR</userId><asOfDate></asOfDate></argLookupBySSNInput></getPlanLookUpBySSN></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
```

---

Same client stub code will be deployed in UAT. The server(WebSphere) and service URL are same as in dev. but the element position are sorted in alphabetical order in UAT box. Hence the web service won't accept the request xml, instead it throws an error.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><soapenv:Body><getPlanLookUpBySSN xmlns="http://example.com"><argLookupBySSNInput xmlns=""><applicationId>IVR</applicationId><asOfDate></asOfDate><client>PC</client><ivrInd>Y</ivrInd><scrollIndicator></scrollIndicator><scrollKey></scrollKey><ssn>12345</ssn><type>Dental</type><userId>IVR</userId></argLookupBySSNInput></getPlanLookUpBySSN></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
```

In above xml `<asOfDate>` element postion is changed. Please help us to resolve this issue.

Comment: share your xsd/wsdl, which is used for the above mentioned flow?

Comment: wsdl is confidential information so we wont be share it.

Comment: you have to maintain the sequence in xsd/wsdl so that the generated request goes in a fixed order.

Comment: you are correct @Rishal. In dev box the generated request xml goes in fixed order. but in UAT the generated xml doesn't go in fixed order. If we have configure anything to websphere which if you know please share me.

Comment: not sure what kind of a soap service you have, but this seems odd.  What I've seen with jax-ws is that the "arglookupbySSN" would be completely converted to a java object and it wouldn't care what the order was.

Comment: Can you show some web services spec that says that the xml produced from a wsd/schema must be in the same order that it does in the wsdl/schema?  I can see how you may think this is logical for a single inline wsdl.  However, think about 100s of nested wsdls and schemas.  How would those be resolved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to modify the WSDL and make the schema *getPlanLookUpBySSN* element as of fixed sequence like below and regenerate you client. Something like below.
 tag make the tags sequence rigid.

```
<xs:element name="getPlanLookUpBySSN">
          <xs:complexType>
                 <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element name="argLookupBySSNInput">
                               <xs:complexType>
                                      <xs:sequence>
                                             <xs:element name="applicationId" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
                                             <xs:element name="asOfDate"></xs:element>
                                             <xs:element name="client" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
                                             <xs:element name="ivrInd" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
                                             <xs:element name="scrollIndicator"></xs:element>
                                             <xs:element name="scrollKey"></xs:element>
                                             <xs:element name="ssn" type="xs:int"></xs:element>
                                             <xs:element name="type" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
                                             <xs:element name="userId" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
                                         </xs:sequence>
                                      <xs:attribute name="xmlns" type="xs:string"></xs:attribute>
                                  </xs:complexType>
                           </xs:element>
                    </xs:sequence>
                 <xs:attribute name="xmlns" type="xs:string"></xs:attribute>
             </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
```